# C++: Class - Overloaded Constructors - single variable?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am not sure how to ask this, but hopefully someone will understand. Lets say I have 3 different classes. Class A, Class B and Class C. Class C should take either Class A or Class B as a parameter in the constructor and store it in a private variable.

This is easy with overloaded constructors. My question is how can Class C automagically use the correct class depending on what constructor was used? (Note these 2 classes are similar, but come from different libraries and thus no shared base class). Is this possible with templates? I do not have a lot of experience with templates.

Comment: Can you make `class C` a template, or do you relying on it being a non-template?

Comment: @juanchopanza  "Is this possible with templates?" :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore "possible with templates" does not mean "make C a class template". If it were possible, it would be the easiest solution, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it quite easy with templates:

```
class A;
class B;

template<class AorB>
class C
{
public:
    C(AorB aorb)
        : aorb_(aorb)
        { }

private:
    AorB aorb_;
};
```

What this does is that inside the class `C` the identifier `AorB` can be used as any other class, in fact it doesn't even have to be an instance of `A` or `B` but can be *any* class.

Can be used like this:

```
A myA;
B myB;

C<A> myCWithA(myA);
C<B> myCWithB(myB);
```

---

There is however one thing you have to remember when creating classes using templates: The specification and implementation can no longer be split into separate header and source files. All of the code have to be available in the header file.

The syntax of the member functions are also a little different.

Example:

```
template<class T>
class C
{
public:
    ...

    void someFunction();
};

template<class T>
C<T>::someFunction()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want. @juanchopanza if you have an alternative, I would still love to see it. –

Comment: @Talib An alternative would be reasonably complicated. If you can live with a class template there is no need for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with templates:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class C {
public:
    C(T const& ref) : ref(ref) {}
    void doStuff() const {
        ref.doStuff();
    }
private:
    T ref;
};

class A {
public:
    void doStuff() const {
        std::cout << "A::doStuff" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    void doStuff() const {
        std::cout << "B::doStuff" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    C<A> foo((A()));
    foo.doStuff();

    C<B> bar((B()));
    bar.doStuff();
}
```